# How do I query mongo to show the results in the format I want?

Tags: json, mongodb

completely new to mongodb and I am trying to get a query working for some reports in the format I need.

Here is the results from my Assets Collection:

```
db.getCollection('Asset').find({})
```

Result:

```
    /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58176238f23ee4040a48846c"),
    "AssetTypeId" : "58176225f23ee4040a48846b",
    "AssetTypeName" : "Chairs",
    "Fields" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5770ae6cf500fd7675c234c5",
            "Title" : "Asset Name",
            "Value" : "Fancy Chair"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "576b7593f500fd7675c234b9",
            "Title" : "Status",
            "Value" : "Missing"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "57b2b52b31f7c7d80db34a23",
            "Title" : "Location",
            "Value" : "Office")
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5817638ff23ee4040a48846e"),
    "AssetTypeId" : "58176225f23ee4040a48846b",
    "AssetTypeName" : "Chairs",
    "Fields" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5770ae6cf500fd7675c234c5",
            "Title" : "Asset Name",
            "Value" : "Basic Chair"
        },  
        {
            "_id" : "576b7593f500fd7675c234b9",
            "Title" : "Status",
            "Value" : "Stores"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "57b2b52b31f7c7d80db34a23",
            "Title" : "Location",
            "Value" : "Home")
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581767f3f23ee4040a488471"),
    "AssetTypeId" : "5817678ff23ee4040a488470",
    "AssetTypeName" : "Table",
    "Fields" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5770ae6cf500fd7675c234c5",
            "Title" : "Asset Name",
            "Value" : "Fancy Table"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "576b7593f500fd7675c234b9",
            "Title" : "Status",
            "Value" : "Active"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "57b2b52b31f7c7d80db34a23",
            "Title" : "Location",
            "Value" : "Office")
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the end result I'm trying to get from the query:

```
[
{"Asset Name":"Fancy Chair", "Status":"Missing","Location":"Office","AssetTypeName":"Chairs"},
{"Asset Name":"Basic Chair", "Status":"Stores","Location":"Office","AssetTypeName":"Chairs"},
{"Asset Name":"Fancy Table", "Status":"Active","Location":"Office","AssetTypeName":"Table"}
]
```

Comment: Please add whatever you've tried so far and somebody will work with you to make it right and doing this way will attract more people.

Comment: This is as far as I have got:

Comment: db.getCollection('Asset').find({},{'Fields.Title':1, 'Fields.Value':1, "AssetTypeName":1});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to transform the mongodb **Asset** results into your preferred format by iterating your results and creating a new array of objects:

```
function processAssets(assets){
   var results = [];
   for (var i=0;i<assets.length;i++){
      var asset = assets[i];
      var result = {AssetTypeName: asset.AssetTypeName};
      //AssetTypeName is not in the Fields array
      for (var f=0;f<asset.Fields.length;f++){
         var field = asset.Fields[f];
         result[field.Title] = field.Value;
         //this will make result['Asset Name'] = 'Fancy Chair', etc
      }
      results.push(result);
   } 
   return results;
}
```

A more mongodb way is to use the cursor.map method:

```
db.Asset.find().map(function(asset){
    var result = {AssetTypeName: asset.AssetTypeName};
    for (var f=0;f<asset.Fields.length;f++){
       var field = asset.Fields[f];
       result[field.Title] = field.Value;
    }
    return result;
});
```

Comment: I take it thats the only way and it can't be outputted in the query? Just trying to save time on building reports without then parsing the results through javascript to the correct format.

Comment: I added a more mongo-centric method but should have the same effect

Comment: Trying the cursor.map method but I am getting " Error: Line 3: Unexpected token : " when I try to run it.

Comment: Oops. Typo. Fixed in both methods.